# "IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING" error in JSON file

Tags: android, json, android-studio, illegalstateexception

I'm making a project (for a programming class in uni) but when I try to run it in Android Studio, a warning appears very briefly in the emulator:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 5 column 21 path $[0].dateOfBirth`

This is my JSON file:

```
{
  "fighters": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Karl",
      "dateOfBirth": "20-03-1975",
      "level": 4,
      "image": "karl.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Geralt",
      "dateOfBirth": "16-08-1964",
      "level": 8,
      "image": "Geralt.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Darrak",
      "dateOfBirth": "25-11-1940",
      "level": 5,
      "image": "Darrak.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Jafar",
      "dateOfBirth": "09-02-1920",
      "level": 9,
      "image": "Jafar.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Cornelius",
      "dateOfBirth": "28-06-1988",
      "level": 2,
      "image": "Cornelius.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Laila",
      "dateOfBirth": "18-10-1998",
      "level": 5,
      "image": "Laila.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Marianne",
      "dateOfBirth": "01-03-1975",
      "level": 7,
      "image": "Marianne.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Petro",
      "dateOfBirth": "10-07-1974",
      "level": 10,
      "image": "Petro.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Ordelia",
      "dateOfBirth": "18-05-1985",
      "level": 5,
      "image": "Ordelia.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Lucina",
      "dateOfBirth": "21-09-1992",
      "level": 9,
      "image": "Lucina.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Hugo",
      "dateOfBirth": "16-07-1938",
      "level": 6,
      "image": "Hugo.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Sildar",
      "dateOfBirth": "19-12-1980",
      "level": 3,
      "image": "Sildar.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Zenok",
      "dateOfBirth": "30-10-1999",
      "level": 1,
      "image": "Zenok.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Violet",
      "dateOfBirth": "02-04-2001",
      "level": 8,
      "image": "Violet.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "name": "Tamara",
      "dateOfBirth": "13-06-1963",
      "level": 4,
      "image": "Tamara.png"
    }
  ],
  "encounters": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "fighterId": 1,
      "amount_of_monsters": 4,
      "difficulty": "Medium"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "fighterId": 5,
      "amount_of_monsters": 1,
      "difficulty": "Easy"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "fighterId": 5,
      "amount_of_monsters": 2,
      "difficulty": "Medium"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "fighterId": 7,
      "amount_of_monsters": 1,
      "difficulty": "Hard"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "fighterId": 11,
      "amount_of_monsters": 7,
      "difficulty": "Medium"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "fighterId": 7,
      "amount_of_monsters": 2,
      "difficulty": "Easy"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "fighterId": 14,
      "amount_of_monsters": 10,
      "difficulty": "Extreme"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "fighterId": 13,
      "amount_of_monsters": 4,
      "difficulty": "Medium"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "fighterId": 7,
      "amount_of_monsters": 5,
      "difficulty": "Hard"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "fighterId": 3,
      "amount_of_monsters": 5,
      "difficulty": "Easy"
    }
  ]
}
```

Line 5 is "name": "Karl",

There's something wrong with my dateOfBirth attribute and I don't know why, because to me the syntax looks correct. I've tried reinstalling the app and rebuilding the project but that didn't work.

This is my first time posting a question on StackOverflow, so apologies if something isn't clear.
If anyone is able to help, I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT (additional info)

I'm using Android Studio 3.6, API 29.

Android Gradle Plugin Version: 3.5.3

Gradle Version: 5.4.1

I use GSON to parse the JSON

JDK 11

This is the function I used for the GSON class:

```
fun getFighters(): Observable<Array<Fighter>> {
        val observable = Observable.create<Array<Fighter>> { emitter ->
            try {
                var connection = connect("${BASE_URL}/fighters")
                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val fighters = gson.fromJson(
                    InputStreamReader(connection.inputStream),
                    Array<Fighter>::class.java
                )
                for (fighter in fighters) {
                    connection = connect("${BASE_URL}/${fighter.image}")
                    fighter.imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.inputStream)
                }
                emitter.onNext(fighters)
            } catch(e: Exception) {
                emitter.onError(e)
            }
        }
        return observable
    }
```

The BASE_URL is just a testing url since the assignment we have to do doesn't require to actually deploy the app. The for loop is to show the images of the Fighters in a RecyclerView list, so therefore I used a bitmap. Furthermore, here's the basic Fighter data class:

```
data class Fighter(
    val id: Number,
    val name: String,
    val dateOfBirth: LocalDate,
    val level: Number,
    val image: String,
    var imageBitmap: Bitmap
)
```

Comment: Hi there ;-)

Thanks for your question but it might be missing a few information to guide the others.

You might want to add the version of the JDK you're using, the library you're using to parse the JSON, the version of Android, etc.

Everything that might help others to supply you with a constructive answer ;-)

Thanks.

Comment: @Ethenyl Thanks for the suggestion! I added as much additional info as possible.

Comment: @FunkyYosh please post your GSON class that you use for parsing this JSON

Comment: @ReazMurshed I added that and some other things, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you! Please see my answer below and let me know if that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the class that you are using for parsing the JSON should be modified as follows.

```
data class Fighter(
    val id: Number,
    val name: String,
    val dateOfBirth: String,
    val level: Number,
    val image: String,
    var imageBitmap: Bitmap
)
```

The `dateOfBirth` is stored as a `String` in your JSON and you need to fetch that in that way. If you need to convert the value to a `LocalDate` object, you can always do that later after parsing the information. I hope that helps!